# I want to use some Variables inside the manifest file KubernetesManifest@1

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I haven't seen any option or documented behavior in [KubernetesManifest@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v1) which makes it possible to replace variables in a yaml file.

Let's have the following Service yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: $(SERVICE_NAME)
  name: $(SERVICE_NAME)
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: $(SERVICE_NAME)
  type: ClusterIP
```

Now I would expect that the tasks renderType have something like variables or envsubst but the only supported types are `'helm' # 'helm' | 'kompose' | 'kustomize'`. None of them are able to substitute the Variables in the Manifest.

The question is is there a better way then `envsubst` before applying the Manifests?

Comment: [Helm](https://helm.sh) can definitely do variable substitution, though it needs a bit more wiring than just writing `{{ .Values.serviceName }}` in the YAML files.

Comment: Thanks but this implies that a values.yaml should be maintained. I prefer this solution https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10026#issuecomment-942367623 because helm can' use Variables from env, similar probem exists with kustomize https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2052

Comment: @Aleksandar that's not true - in helm you can use `--set` flag also.
`helm install <other-chart-options> --set serviceName=$SERVICE_NAME` should work

Comment: @ravenwing you are right when using plain helm. The question here is about Azure DevOps Pipeline task `KubernetesManifest@1`. I haven't seen an option to add a `set` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, Pipeline variables cannot be passed directly to YAML files and the Pipeline task: KubernetesManifest@1 has no built-in option can set the pipeline variable value in YAML file.

> The question is is there a better way then envsubst before applying the Manifests?

I would like to share the following two methods to replace variable values in Service.yaml file.

Method1: We can use the **Replace Tokens task** from the [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are the steps:

1.Set the #{varname}# (e.g. #{SERVICE_NAME}# ) in the YAML file.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: #{SERVICE_NAME}#
  name: #{SERVICE_NAME}#
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: #{SERVICE_NAME}#
  type: ClusterIP
```

2.Set the variable `$(SERVICE_NAME)` in Azure Pipeline and use the Replace tokens task.

```
stages:
- stage: dev
  variables:
    SERVICE_NAME: xxx
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@5
      inputs:
        rootDirectory: 'folderpath'
        targetFiles: 'service.yaml'
        encoding: 'auto'
        tokenPattern: 'default'
        writeBOM: true
        actionOnMissing: 'warn'
        keepToken: false
        actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
        enableTransforms: false
        enableRecursion: false
        useLegacyPattern: false
        enableTelemetry: true
    - task:  KubernetesManifest@1
```

Method2: we can use **sed** command to replace the variable in Service.yaml file.

Here is an example:

```
variables:
  SERVICE_NAME: xxx

steps:
- bash: 'sed -i -e ''s/#{SERVICE_NAME}#/$(SERVICE_NAME)/g'' Service.yaml'
  displayName: 'Replace Variable'

- task:  KubernetesManifest@1
```

These two methods can replace variables in yaml file before applying the Manifests.

Comment: I will use the `Method1`. Thank you for the nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussions, you may consider running `helm install` command in this pipeline task `HelmDeploy@0` instead.

See more details on [HelmDeploy@0 - Package and deploy Helm charts v0 task | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/helm-deploy-v0?view=azure-pipelines)